# When using Google Apps (G-Suite) as an Identity provider - How to differentiate between Partner users and Full license users?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, partner-communities, google-apps

There is a similar question in here already with a solution but I am stuck on a particular step. ([Google SSO for Partner Community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156342/google-sso-for-partner-community))

I am a Google Suite Admin and SF admin and have setup SAML so that people in our domain can login to Salesforce PRODUCTION as long as their email address is the same as their Salesforce username. (eg. "fullSFuser@xyz.org")

This part is working fine (Huzzah!), BUT we also have people on the same G-Suite (same domain) and they ONLY have the Partner user license, because we are an non-profit scraping by and they don't need all the features of the full license.

so the GOAL is 
a) for these partner users (eg email="partnerSFuser@xyz.org") to use SSO, and;
b) it will login to their partner usernames (also "partnerSFuser@xyz.org"), and;
c) it will take those users to a specific Partner portal URL. (eg. https://xyz.force.com/staffcommunity) Since they can't access production directly.

SETTINGS so far:

Using the Google SAML wizard - I got the settings below. Imagine the part that is blacked out with anything is the domain name: xyz - my boss wants me to be extra safe ;) so imagine the ACS to say https://xyz.my.salesforce.com?so=00D80000000abcd

[image: SAML setup]

Now the instructions from another user mentioned this:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_portals.htm&language=en_US&type=0

And I see the note about:

> In addition to the SAML sign-on information that must be gathered and shared
>   with your identity provider, you must supply your information provider with 
>   the Organization ID and the Portal ID. In the SAML assertion that is sent from
>   your identity provider, the portal_id and organization_id must be added as
>   attributes.
>
> Note:
>   You can leave these attributes blank to differentiate between portal and platform users. For example, when blank, the user is a regular platform user and when populated, the user is a portal user.

[image]

So I THINK it is telling me to put in:
**organization_id** where it says *Enter application Attribute*
and then choose from a field controlled in G-Suite (Category: Basic, Contact, Employee Details, HR) and then the user field (eg. First Name, Last Name, cost center).

Q1: In that case: Am I on the right track? 
Q2: Do I need to add some user fields in G-Suite when I add users?
Q3: How would I redirect those Users to the community? I have the following endpoints setup in SF... (under SAML Single Sign-On Settings)

Salesforce Login URL
https://xyz.my.salesforce.com?so=00D80000000abcd

Digital iDE Community Login URL 
https://xyz.force.com/digital/login?so=00D80000000abcd

OAuth 2.0 Token Endpoint
https://xyz.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?so=00D80000000abcd

Thanks for the going through these lengthy questions - I just wanted to give as much info and steps done so far. Thank you for help in advance.

Cheers,
Gordon